# Spring-Security DAOAuthenticationProvider asks for ID for authentication

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring-Security on top of a Spring-MVC application. I have my own implementation of UserDAO, userDetailsService. I am trying to authenticate by checking from database(ofcourse). I reach till the login page, everything seems to be working fine, but when I login, I get an error :

ERROR:

```
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.WirTauschen.model.User. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110)
```

I do not know where am I retrieving or working with user's id.  I am posting the code below.

LoginService :

```
 @Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            UserDetails userDetails = null;

         User user = userDao.findByName(username);
            if(user == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");} //Never specify which one was it exactly
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(user);
    }
}
```

Assembler

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    User buildUserFromUserEntity(com.WirTauschen.model.User userEntity){
        String username = userEntity.getUsername();
        String password = userEntity.getPassword();
      //  int id = userEntity.getId();
        boolean enabled = userEntity.isActive();
        boolean accountNonExpired = userEntity.isAccountNonExpired();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = userEntity.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        boolean accountNonLocked = userEntity.isAccountNonLocked();

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        User user1 = new User(username,password,enabled,accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,authorities);
        return  user1;
        }
}
```

User :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="registration")
public class User implements UserDetails{
    private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id=UUID.randomUUID().toString();
   // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "my_entity_seq_gen")
    //@SequenceGenerator(name ="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName = "MY_ENTITY_SEQ")


    @OneToMany
    private Set<ProductBasic> productBasic;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String Username;

    @Column(name = "displayname")
    private String DisplayName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "companyname")
    private String CompanyName;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String FirstName;

    @Column(name = "middlename")
    private String MiddleName;

private String role="ROLE_USER";


    @Transient
    private final String PERMISSION_PREFIX = "ROLE_USER";
    @Transient
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    public User() {
            this.authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(USER_AUTH);
    }

    public User(String Username, String password, String Role){
        this.Username = Username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = Role;
        if((role == null) || role.isEmpty()){ role = "ROLE_USER";}

    }

 @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }
```

*Update sequence code*

```
@Id
@Column(name = "sortcanvasid")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sortcanvas_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sortcanvas_gen", sequenceName = "sortcanvas_seq")
private int sortCanvasId;
```

Comment: could you provide USER class ?

Comment: @Pracede : Added...please check edits

Comment: The problem seems to be on private String id=UUID.randomUUID().toString(); i think it would work if you had a Integer instead of String. But i did not found why

Comment: I had int before, but I wanted to implement some other functionality so I changed it to String, the same problem exists.

Comment: Did you get a solution? I am having same issue

Comment: @ChrisJKikoti : to be honest I don't remembre the issue, but as pracede said, it might be related to the UUID I am generating. That's why I am now using a sequence. I have added the code at bottom of main post, kindly have a look.

Comment: @We are Borg thanks for responding

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your User class not implementing UserDetails Morever it might not be having proper return type of the getID method

Comment: Hi. Added the user class which is implementing UserDetails, please have a look.

Comment: It Seems me that the JDBC framework whichever you are using is making an problem it, expects the Serializable Key of the bean User to be as Integer but its getting String instead of it. So the issue is coming.
Due to this your spring sec login is not working.

if  using Hibernate map it to appropriate Column. and Use GeneratedValue etc annotation

Comment: Also provide the getter setter methods... of each member of the User Bean